# timed out while receiving the initial server greeting

Tags: linux, email, smtp, postfix-mta, connection-timeout

I'm trying to host a postfix mail server.I have a box with a fixed IP and also a mx record and spf record that link my box IP to my dns record. I can telnet to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25 but when I send a mail to me@gmail.com, I still receive this error

**mailq**

```
-Queue ID-  --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
CB502D9735*     389 Tue Jul 18 01:28:17  root@mydomain.com
                                         me@gmail.com

37A54D8C06      389 Tue Jul 18 00:26:34  root@mydomain.com
(conversation with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.200.26] timed out while receiving the initial server greeting)
                                         me@gmail.com


BBC43D9557      389 Tue Jul 18 01:11:20  root@mydomain.com
(conversation with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.200.26] timed out while receiving the initial server greeting)
                                         me@gmail.com
```

```
telnet alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25


Trying 74.125.200.27...
Connected to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [sf] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Notice that you're never receiving the greeting message from the SMTP server when you telnet.

Answer (score 0):

### SMTP tests using telnet - waiting for SMTP greeting message

How long have you waited for SMTP greeting message? [test using telnet]
Problems with reverse DNS may trigger DNS resolution timeouts (typically 75s).
Some spam bots detection procedures intentionally delay SMTP greeting message.

Wait at least 5 minutes for SMTP greeting message.  **Exact** delay may provide a valuable hint.

Your configured timeout for waiting for SMTP greeting may be too short.